# Disable List locking Sitecore List Management Module

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

While adding a new contact programmatically in Sitecore. An error occurs *"The list cannot be used or edited because it is currently in use or related sources has been locked"*, Is there any way to disable list locking?

Answer (score 0):

The list locking can be disabled OOTB starting from Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 as stated in the [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update2/Release%20Notes) (see the 'Disabling the list locking mechanism' section). Please note that disabling list locking may lead to inconsistency when managing lists:

> - Disabling list locking can lead to inconsistencies in the number of contacts that are available in a contact list or in an EXM dispatch, versus the number of expected contacts.
> - A contact list can be used in EXM immediately after import, even if most of the contacts in the list have not been processed yet. This can result in an email being sent to a smaller audience than was intended. In these scenarios, to ensure that the list count is as expected before proceeding with an EXM dispatch, check the list count in the List Manager.
> - Incomplete contact lists are available for use as sources for other lists. This can result in incomplete child lists. 
>     In these scenarios, to ensure that the list count is as expected before proceeding with a new list, check the list count of any source lists in the List Manager.
> - Multiple users can edit incomplete contact lists at the same time. If the list sources are edited while the contact associations are being written and indexed, the resulting lists may not match your expectations.

In order to disable list locking, *turn on* the `Sitecore.ListManagement.DisableListLocking.config.disabled` configuration file in the `App_Config\Include\ListManagement\` folder.

Comment: Sitecore.ListManagement.DisableListLocking.config.disabled file is unavailable in my build.